Why does my query slow down massively when combining two fast WHERE clauses?
My table in an SQLite database is separately indexed on all columns. These queries both execute in under 15ms:
select id from MyTable where end > 1704067100000 (returns 1 record)
select id from MyTable where start < 1704067900000 (returns almost all records)
This query (with where statements combined) takes 500ms:
select id From MyTable where end > 1704067100000 and start < 1704067900000

This also takes ~500ms:
select id
from (select id, start
    from MyTable
    where end > 1704067100000)
where start < 1704067900000

Does anyone know why? And how can I fix it?
I ran:
explain query plan select id From MyTable where end > 1704067100000 and start < 1704067900000

And got:
SEARCH TABLE MyTable USING INDEX IX_MyTable_Start (Start<?)


Can you try running explain query plan select id From MyTable where end > 1704067100000 and start < 1704067900000 and add the output to the question?

Can you see if this runs faster: select id from MyTable where end > 1704067100000 intersect select id from MyTable where start < 1704067900000.

@Dogbert That's faster, but still slow (~185ms)

I think this would force it to use the index on end first: select id from MyTable where id in (select id from MyTable where end > 1704067100000) and start < 1704067900000.

It's a step forward at least - it runs in 10ms. However.... if I change the times to an equivalent period located at the start of the table, it then runs really slow again @300ms (the table has records representing timeslots, and they happen to be ordered chronologically - the example in my question was locating a record at the end)

Check out this section of the docs: https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#choosing_between_multiple_indexes and the ANALYZE statement linked on that page, might help.

A (sub)query can only use a single index. To speed this up you'd probably need to create a single index that covered both the start and end columns

I'd look into trying to use a r tree table; this is the sort of range based lookup it's meant for.

Thanks for the tips. In the end, after realising I was forced to use a single index (even after running the ANALYZE command it was then slow in the middle of the table because it could still only choose one index), I realised that because my design has evolved to all my time slots being the same length, I don't even need the end column, and can query all my ranges on the "start" column which has given me excellent results.
